# Uploadifive mobile support? (Uploadify)

Tags: uploadify, uploadifive

I'm using Uploadify on my website which uses flash and it doesn't work on Android Chrome, but does the paid HTML5 version work on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/8328) on their forums, a user (in March 2012) had Uploadifive working on their Galaxy Nexus. I'd say that most modern phones should run it if the Galaxy Nexus can do it.

Also, at the end of the day, it's only $5 for the standard license.

Answer (score 0):

Uploadifive didnt work with my Chrome Browser on my Galaxy Note 4. I tried using Firefox browser and it worked. I uploaded the same files on different browsers. So, I guess the issue must be with Chrome on android.